# Does DownloadManager neither reattempt nor broadcast failures on insufficient space?

Tags: android, download-manager

I was looking through the AOSP code in KitKat and noticed this code in `com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread`:

```
/**
 * Stores information about the completed download, and notifies the initiating application.
 */
private void notifyDownloadCompleted(
        State state, int finalStatus, String errorMsg, int numFailed) {
    notifyThroughDatabase(state, finalStatus, errorMsg, numFailed);
    if (Downloads.Impl.isStatusCompleted(finalStatus)) {
        mInfo.sendIntentIfRequested();
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that I see that it won't broadcast a failure due to `STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE_ERROR` because the value is 198 and the check for status completed excludes values less than 200 in `android.provider.Downloads`:

```
    public static final int STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE_ERROR = 198;

    // ...

    public static boolean isStatusCompleted(int status) {
        return (status >= 200 && status < 300) || (status >= 400 && status < 600);
    }
```

I see this code which appears to prevent a download that failed due to insufficient space from ever being retried. See `com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadInfo`:

```
        case Downloads.Impl.STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE_ERROR:
            // avoids repetition of retrying download
            return false;
```

So it seems that if a download fails due to insufficient space no broadcast happens and it is never retried. Is that right? I haven't looked through other versions of AOSP yet to see if they behave in the same way.

In conclusion it seems like someone interested in being notified of the download succeeding or failing needs to not just register for the broadcast but also use a ContentObserver to watch the download ContentProvider for changes.

Comment: Isn't the code 498? What class are you looking at?

Comment: I added the class names to the question.

Comment: Forget my comment. I was looking at the wrong class. That constant is 198 as well for marshmallow and lollipop. Source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/provider/Downloads.java)

Comment: Well it looks that it is as you said, and same goes for all the other "informational" error codes, like 199 (SDCard not mounted). That one should be easy to reproduce.

Comment: Argh, 2+ years later I hit the same bug on Oreo... still a problem!

Comment: Google team says it should retry, but that never happen on my simulator, please comment to them here, they "won't fix it" because it is intentional behaviour: https://issuetracker.google.com/118860049